# Array filter between dates and slice it in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

i have array

```
array(5) { 
    [0]=> string(19) "2012-06-11 08:30:49" 
    [1]=> string(19) "2012-06-07 08:03:54" 
    [2]=> string(19) "2012-05-26 23:04:04" 
    [3]=> string(19) "2012-05-27 08:30:00" 
    [4]=> string(19) "2012-06-08 08:30:55" 
}
```

i want to slice into array <= 2012-06-07 08:30:49

how to get those array?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter object array based on attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722159/how-to-filter-object-array-based-on-attributes)

Comment: @zigrazor - that question is about javascript not PHP

Answer (score 1):

You can use the builtin-fuction `array_filter` for this. The first argument is the array you want to use and the second is the callback for each iteration (each item in the array). We only want dates for each item that <= 2012-06-07 08:30:49 and those items that meets that critera is returned into the final `$result` - variable.

```
$result = array_filter($arr, function($data_item) {
    return $data_item <= "2012-06-07 08:30:49";
});
```

For more information look about the array_filter() look at: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Comment: Are you sure that comparing __dates__ like __strings__ will work as expected?

Comment: @u_mulder - I have tested serveral different dates and times. And I got the expected result - so yes. (It worked in this case anyway). Please tell me if there is an issue with this! (I want to know in that case)

Comment: @NicoHaase - I thought it was kind of self explanatory but I guess you can never get to detailed. I have supplied a small text how it works.

Answer (score 1):

```
$dates = ["2012-06-11 08:30:49",
        "2012-06-07 08:03:54",
        "2012-05-26 23:04:04",
        "2012-05-27 08:30:00",
        "2012-06-08 08:30:55",];
$filtered_array=array();
foreach ($dates as $value) {
    if($value <= "2012-06-07 08:30:49"){
        array_push($filtered_array, $value);
    }
}

print_r($filtered_array);
```

result:

Array ( [0] => 2012-06-07 08:03:54 [1] => 2012-05-26 23:04:04 [2] => 2012-05-27 08:30:00 )

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but i prefer to use array_filter